# Change the color of the blue sharepoint toolbar when clicking on the "Blog" option

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, blog, social

We can change the color of the blue SharePoint toolbar by changing the  color using the below code in the master page.

```
  div#suiteBarLeft{
  background-color: red;
   }
```

When we click on newsfeed, About Me, Apps and Tasks this works fine, however when we click on Blog then the toolbar changes back to Blue, which seems very strange.

Anybody has any idea as to why this will happen.

[image]

Comment: Use the inspector tools in Firefox, might help you to know which property is assigning it _blue_. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013  MySite quick launch components as below:

1. About me(person.aspx) & NewsFeed(default.aspx) are two pages in the
   same site collection root site.This site collection will be common
   for all users.
2. Apps and Blog are 2 seperate sub sites in another Site Collection ie
   personal Site Collection of each user.

Clicking on "Apps" will take you to "Site Contents" page of the Personal Site collection root site of particular user.

Clicking on Blog will take you to a blog sub site in the personal site collection of user.

Whenever you deploy custom master page, in order for the master page to applied properly check the following:

1. Feature "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" is
   activated for both the site collection (root Site Collection of
       MySite and personal site collection of users).
2. Make sure "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" is activated in the
   root site of both the site collection as well as the Blog sub site 
   of the personal site collection of the user.

Make sure "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" feature is activated in the Blog sub site , since in your case the Apps sub site is displaying the master page changes the "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" and the "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" might be already activated.

This Article explains the [MySite Quick launch components](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/deep-dive-confusing-sharepoint-2013-mysite-quick-launch-left-nav/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SharePoint Color Palette tool:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182

Exam the spcolor-file under /_catalogs/Theme/15 in SharePoint designer. NoCode ;-).

Comment: OP already has the CSS, but wants it to only run when on a blog

Comment: Actually I want it to run for all, but for some reason when I click blog the color reverts back to Blue.

Comment: Is it using a different masterpage ?

Comment: That is what we need to find out... how do we see what master page it is using.

Answer (score 0):

Does the blog site have publishing enabled?  You should be able to switch to your custom masterpage after enabling publishing.  Instead of activating Publishing and changing the MasterPage through Site Settings, you could do it via PowerShell

```
$w = get-spweb http://<yourserver>/sites/parentsite/blogsite
$w.CustomMasterURL = <<your custom master page>>
$w.update()
```

You could also open the site in SharePoint designer - navigate to _Catalogs/MasterPage - right click on the master page and set is as the custom master page

Suggestions shamelessly stolen from [TechNet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bef41d31-1deb-4edf-a89a-c77138100f41/master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-blog-site)

Answer (score 0):

As I had said in my comment, try checking the `CSS` rule associated with `#suiteBarLeft`. It might well be overridden by some other property which is giving it `blue` color. Try setting the property using Inspector tools will help you find the issue easily.

```
#suiteBarLeft {
      background-color:red !important;  
}
```

//you may want to use !important for applying this rule specifically.